# How to calculate Azimuth & Elevation of objects relative to camera using cam quaternion ...?

Tags: 3d, camera, vector-graphics, quaternions

I have a camera quaternion (a,b,c,d) and a cam position (camX, camY, camZ)
I have an object with 3d coordinates (x,y,z)

I need to calculate azimuth, elevation of objects relatively to the cam view direction & plane.

First question
If I put the object in center of my view, f I rotate the cam, translate it, I should have the same azimuth value, right ??
I don't have that.

Second question, the calculation.
I'm doing object coordinates - cam position, in order to translate the object to the cam.
I'm taken the resulting coordinates and make the sandwich product with the quaternion and its conjugate. (I followed this for the pseudo code : [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_et_rotation_dans_l'espace](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_et_rotation_dans_l%27espace))

Then, I have a vector result and I take X & Z component and calculate the atan2

Does it seem right ?

any leads or explanation would help me a lot in my struggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second calculation you've described seems pretty close to correct, but with a couple of underlying assumptions that you should verify.  I'll discuss those in a moment.  Your first question, however, doesn't make sense.

Both rotation and translation will almost always change the azimuth value.  If you're looking straight at the object, `azimuth==0`.  If you then rotate 90° to the left, the azimuth has clearly also changed by 90°.  If you then take a step (of length `x`) forward, your azimuth has just gained an additional `atan(x/d)` degrees (where `d` is the original distance that the object was ahead of you).

As for finding the azimuth and elevation, your computation depends on assumptions about the default orientation of the world.  I.e., if your camera coordinates are [0,0,0] the quaternion is the identity rotation, then what direction is the camera facing and what direction is up?  Typically, 'up' is `+y` and forward is `-z`.  If that's the case, then you'll compute thus:

```
p = q'*(obj-cam)*q
az = atan2(p.x,-p.z)
el = asin(p.y/sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z))
```

Where `q'` is the quaternion conjugate/inverse (just negate `q.w`) and `*` is quaternion multiplication (the `w` component of the vector is set to zero).

Comment: Hello JCooper. First, many thanks for your answer. My first question has been to badly explained and I'm sorry about that. I wanted to say: imagine your cam look at the object which is in center of your view. az = 0, el=0. if I move the camera "around" the object, by keeping the object in the center of my view, I should still have az=0 & el=0 right? this is just what I wanted to say with my ugly english :-/ I'll implement what you gave me quite soon and let you know. I have my cam quaternion, but only x,y,z of my object.. I guess I have to use 0,x,y,z for the object to make the calculation..?!

Comment: @gluon That's right, if you rotate around the object, while still facing it, the azimuth and elevation don't change.

Comment: And when you transform a vector with a quaternion, you augment the vector with a leading zero as you said, assuming that your quaternions are ordered as [w,x,y,z].  Sometimes quaternions are ordered as [x,y,z,w].  You'll need to know which you have.

Comment: maxi thanks for your help, @JCooper. I will implement that in next hours. Currently preparing 2 music live performances today.. yep. my quat coming from my camera handler is w,x,y,z Just to be sure I correctly understood Hamilton's quaternions... using them, I won't have any singularities & gimbal lock right ??

Comment: @gluon If you're multiplying lots of quaternions together, you need to be careful to renormalize.  If the quaternion's not unit-length some strange things can happen.  You're correct that quaternions themselves do not suffer from gimbal lock.  However, sometimes people still experience gimbal lock when they use quaternions because they build the quaternion out of Euler angles.  So don't do that.  The only time I can think of singularities arising with quaternions is when you try to interpolate between two quaternions that represent rotations of 180 degrees.  Probably not a problem here.