# Calculate azimuth & elevation relative to another camera

Tags: math, vector, graphics, 3d

As shown in the figure, I need to find azimuth and elevation of point P wrt to Camera 2. Point P(a,b,c) has co-ordinates defined with respect to Camera 1 (X,Y,Z) with a direction of view vector (x,y,z) as the origin which is distance (d) vertically below the Camera 2 (both cameras are in the same plane). I can find the azimuth/elevation using [How to calculate azimut & elevation relative to a camera direction of view in 3D ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967130/how-to-calculate-azimut-elevation-relative-to-a-camera-direction-of-view-in-3d) for point P with respect to Camera 1 but I want to find the azimuth/elevation wrt Camera 2. I am confused about how should I do this?

If add 'd' distance to Camera 1 co-ordinates to get Camera 2 co-ordinates (X,Y+d,Z), keeping the direction of view vector same (as both Cameras are in same plane) and Point P same, perform the same calculation for Camera 2. It gives out incorrect results. How do I do this for Camera 2?

[image]

Projection in Image Planes:

[image]

Comment: Your procedure for finding the parameters for camera 2 is correct, but double-check that all coordinates and directions actually correspond with what you have presented here and that your calculations are correct. It is really easy to make some mistake. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: If I view point A (azimuth, elevation) wrt to Camera 1 in Camera 1 image plane, the point appears correctly on the object P. If I view the same point A wrt to Camera 2 in Camera 2 image plane the point shifts further down by some value instead of moving up that is It moves away from the original object P.

Comment: Added image for a better understanding.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to do this? If you move the camera up, the object should appear further down in its the field of view. It's like raising your head, right? - everything is translated downwards?

Comment: That's right, but If I find the elevation/azimuth wrt to Camera 2, that point should coincide with the original point P right? If I find point wrt to Camera 1, then shifting down makes sense but wrt to Camera 2 it should still overlap with the original point.