# How to convert a Eigen::Quaternion<float> to a Matrix4f?

Tags: c++, matrix, quaternions

As the title says, i have a problem to convert a `Quaternion` to a `Matrix4f`. `Eigen` has the method `Quaternion.toRotationMatrix()` which gives me a `Matrix3f`. 
Now i need a `Matrix4f` ( because our program is designed to take only `Matrix4f`), is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: It depends on the application, but you could try creating the `Matrix4f` with the 3 components of the `Matrix3f`, plus a `1` as the 4th (`w`) component.  But as I said, it definitely depends on the application - not all quaternions even represent rotation matrices.

Comment: I second Rob I's comment. Most matrix implementations take the 4th column "as position vector" and the 4th row as the "scaling".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**M3 to M4**

The answere is already there, given by Rob and Najzero.
In most cases, it will be sufficient to construct the matrix as follows:

m3:

```
|a00|a01|a02|
|a10|a11|a12|
|a20|a21|a22|
```

to m4:

```
|a00|a01|a02| 0 | 
|a10|a11|a12| 0 | 
|a20|a21|a22| 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

The 4x4 matrix does not only allow to rotate a vector, but also to shift(translate) and scale (in all 3 directions) any vector. So basically you got a full transformation matrix - thats why it is often used in computer graphics, describing the transformation of an object. Depending on row-column order, we might identify the matrix as:

```
|rot|rot|rot| sx | 
|rot|rot|rot| sy | 
|rot|rot|rot| sz |
| x | y | z | 1 |
```

with sx,sy,sz as scaling coefficients, and x,y,z as translation coefficients.

PS: of course, if you want to rotate a vector with m4, you will than have to use a 4-dimensional vector, e.g. (x,y,z,w) with w=1 (in most cases).

**The direct approach**

[Convert Quaternion rotation to rotation matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556260/convert-quaternion-rotation-to-rotation-matrix)

And my personal recommendation:
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/
There you will find also other transformations, backtrafos and so on.

Comment: `Eigen::Matrix3f mat3 = Eigen::Quaternionf(W, X, Y, Z).toRotationMatrix();
Eigen::Matrix4f mat4 = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
mat4.block(0,0,3,3) = mat3;`

Comment: @user1556435 you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 7):

@Zacharias' answer contains the necessary theory. I just reiterate my earlier comment I made there with the actual Eigen C++ code.

```
Eigen::Matrix3f mat3 = Eigen::Quaternionf(W, X, Y, Z).toRotationMatrix();
Eigen::Matrix4f mat4 = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
mat4.block(0,0,3,3) = mat3;
```

`Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity()` takes care of initializing the ones and zeros of the 4th and last row and column. `mat4.block(0,0,3,3) = mat3` then overwrites the values obtained from the rotation matrix.