# One Quaternion Camera

Tags: opengl, game-development

Would it be possible to represent a 3D Camera using only a Quaternion? I know that most cameras use an Up vector and a Forward vector to represent it's rotation, but couldn't the same rotation be represented as a single Quaternion with the rotation axis being forward, and the w component being the amount from the Y Axis that the camera was rotated. If there is a way to do this, any resources would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quaternions are pretty common for representing rotations.  Sometimes when an object in a game provides forward / up / right vectors, those vectors are derived from the quaternion, which is the "source of truth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, it's not possible to represent a 3D camera using *only* a quaternion. This is because a 3D camera not only has an orientation in space, but also a position, and a projection. The quaternion only describes an orientation.

If you're actually asking whether the rotation component of the camera object could be represented as a quaternion, then the answer in general is yes. Quaternions can be easily converted into rotation matrices ([Convert Quaternion rotation to rotation matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556260/convert-quaternion-rotation-to-rotation-matrix)), and back, so anywhere a rotation matrix is used, a quaternion could also be used (and converted to a rotation matrix where appropriate).