# Convert quaternion from right-handed to left-handed coordinate system

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I my 3d program, the rotation of object is represented by the quaternion like `[0.130526, 0.0, 0.0, 0.991445]`. The program works with right-handed coordinate system with the Z axis pointing up (like in 3ds max):

[image]

On the other hand, my application use **left-handed** coordinate system **and the Y axis is up**:

[image]

How can I transform my quaternion from one coordinate system to another, with the respect for which axis  is up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flipping a quaternion from right to left handed coordianates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274936/flipping-a-quaternion-from-right-to-left-handed-coordianates)

Comment: @PaulR the question you cited is 5yo, covers half of my problem (swapping axes) and has not been answered (besides "you cannot" when I clearly see it working every day - some software is able to convert them for model exporting but I don't have a source code for it, unfortunately).

Comment: @PolGraphic The question now has a good answer! I'll summarize the relevant points here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A rotation of angle x around axis (u,v,w) can be represented by quaternion with real part cos(x/2) and unreal part sin(x/2)*(u,v,w).

If axis coordinates are (u,v,w) in original trihedron, they will be (u,w,v) in your trihedron.

Thus if original quaternion was (a,b,c,d) - a+ib+jc+kd - the quaternion must be transformed to (a,b,d,c) in your trihedron.

**EDIT**

But because your trihedron is left handed, the angle also has to be reversed, so the same rotation can finally be expressed by the quaternion (a,-b,-d,-c) in your trihedron.

Comment: Just to confirm: `a` is the rotation angle in this case, and `b` = `u`, `c` = `v`, `d` = `w`, correct?

Comment: @calvin a is real part of quaternion = cos(x/2), the angle of rotation is x. b,c,d is unreal part of quaternion, equal to axis coordinates u,v,w multiplied by sin(x/2)

Comment: As a follow-up, how does one change the position co-ordinates from right-handed to left-handed? Say I have (x1, y1, z1), is it sufficient that I convert it to (x1,-y1, z1)?

Answer (score 4):

This is a condensed version of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519536/194921) to a slightly different question.

The problem you ask about arises even if the two coordinate systems are same-handed; it turns out that handedness flips don't make the problem significantly harder. Here is how to do it in general.  To change the basis of a quaternion, say from ROS (right-handed, Z up) to Unity (left-handed, Y up):

```
mat3x3 ros_to_unity = /* construct this by hand by mapping input axes to output axes */;
mat3x3 unity_to_ros = ros_to_unity.inverse();
quat q_ros = ...;
mat3x3 m_unity = ros_to_unity * mat3x3(q_ros) * unity_to_ros;
quat q_unity = mat_to_quat(m_unity);
```

Lines 1-4 are simply the method of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519079/194921: "How do you perform a change-of-basis on a matrix?"

Line 5 is interesting; not all matrices convert to quats, but if ros_to_unity is correct, then this conversion will succeed.

Note that this will give you a *correct* result, but it goes through a lot of work -- conversion to and from a matrix, some multiplies, an inversion. But you can examine its results and then write a special-case version that rearranges or flips axes, like the one aka.nice derived.

Answer (score 1):

Geometric algebra solution just for fun.

I'll write **uv** for the *geometric product* of vectors **u** and **v**.
It's commutative for parallel vectors: **uv** = **vu** when **u** ∥ **v**,
anticommutative for orthogonal vectors: **uv = −vu** when **u** ⊥ **v**,
and associative: (**uv**)**w** = **u**(**vw**) = **uvw**.
Furthermore, **uu** = |**u**|² (the square of the length).

Let (**x, y, z**) be the old right-handed basis.
Vectors in the basis are orthogonal, so **xy = −yx**, **yz = −zy**, **zx = −xz**,
and have length 1, so **xx = yy = zz** = 1.

The quaternion basis (1, **i**, **j**, **k**) corresponds to the multivector basis (1, **zy**, **xz**, **yx**).
You can check that all the quaternion identities work.  For example:

- **ij = zyxz = −zyzx = zzyx = yx = k**,
- **k**² = **yxyx** = −**yyxx** = −**xx** = −1,
- **ijk = k**² = −1.

A quaternion in the old basis can be written as s + b⋅**zy** + c⋅**xz** + d⋅**yx**.
A quaternion in the new basis can be written as S + B⋅**yz** + C⋅**xy** + D⋅**zx**. (We've swapped **y** and **z**.)

Solving for the new coefficients, we get S=s, B=−b, C=−d and D=−c.

There are two conventions for writing quaternion coefficients: `[s, b,c,d]` and `[b,c,d, s]`.

- `[s=0.130526, b=0, c=0, d=0.991445]` transforms to `[S=0.130526, B=0, C=-0.991445, D=0]`.
- `[b=0.130526, c=0, d=0, s=0.991445]` transforms to `[B=-0.130526, C=0, D=0, S=0.991445]`.