# How do you transform a quaternion representing the rotation of an object into a left-handed coordinate system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, 3dsmax

Requirement: Export the camera position and rotation Angle in 3ds Max into the game

3ds Max uses the right-handed coordinate system with the Z-axis up, while the game uses the left-handed coordinate system with the Y-axis up. Change the position, exchange Y and Z, but what about the rotation Angle?

Comment: It's really unrealistic to close a Unity question with math answers.  OP just needs the obvious and simple Unity solution here.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910491/1092820) on one of the linked dupes might work.