# Math: How to convert a left-handed transformation matrix to a right handed one

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, rotation, computer-vision

I have a transformation matrix (rotation + translation) which was constructed in a right-handed coordinate system where X is right, Y is up and Z is into the screen.

If I want to apply this same transformation but in a left-handed coordinate system where X is right, Y is **down** and Z is **out of the screen** (is this left handed?) what alterations should I make to the existing transformation matrix.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for _programming_ question.s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> a right-handed coordinate system where X is right, Y is up and Z is into the screen

Then it's a left-handed coordinate system: X is the thumb, Y is the forefinger, Z is the middle-finger. Your right hand should not be able to do what you describe without breaking a few bones :-p

> a left-handed coordinate system where X is right, Y is down and Z is out of the screen

This one is indeed a left-handed coordinate system too.

As for the transformation linking these two, this is a simple 180° rotation around the X axis (beware of the wrist sprain while trying this one), which expresses as the following 3x3 matrix:

```
(1  0  0)
(0 -1  0)
(0  0 -1)
```

You can pre-multiply your transformation with this one!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

@mbrenon's answer is correct. Just to be clear.

Check my answer on this question [Changing a matrix from right-handed to left-handed coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263072/changing-a-matrix-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system/71168853#71168853)

As for your question, let M_ori be transformation matrix you have, M_dst is what you want in target corrdinate system.

[image]