# Three.js rotating and positioning of geometries

Tags: three.js

I try to write an export of an 3-d plant modelling software to Three.js but got stuck with the rotations and translations of the objects.

So far I tried to use quaternions and transformation matrices but both results are not satisfying. For my tests I use a simple binary tree that originally looks like this:

[image]

the results of my export are this:

[image]

You can find the code of both export under

http://ufgb966.forst.uni-goettingen.de/three/test2Quaternion.html

http://ufgb966.forst.uni-goettingen.de/three/test2Matrix.html

It seams that my rotations are made around the wrong point. Each rotation should be done around the origin of each geometry. What would be a method to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Consider the approach taken at (lines 54-73) at [threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_hierarchy.html](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_hierarchy.html)

Comment: @gallygator this approach is using Euler angles which I do not have and recalculating them from the matirx is normally not an good idea.

Comment: I think the issue is how you have constructed your object from its component parts. The goal would be establishing an _object hierarchy_ for your component geometries that would transform _together_ in world space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you haven't already, you might want to take a look at this: [Using Matrices & Object3Ds in THREE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Using-Matrices-&-Object3Ds-in-THREE) and this [How to use matrix for transformation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1593), it helped me out. Also note that three.js uses a right handed coordinate system which you probably know.

If you export from blender, try -Z Forward, Y up.

Comment: It was a "right-handed vs. left-handed coordinate system" problem. Following this [matrix transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1264880/2421048) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you must change sequence of translation and rotation transformations - the problem is in transformations sequence.