# Homography matrix decomposition- conversion from right hand to left hand coordinate system

Tags: computer-vision, coordinate-systems, homography, matrix-decomposition

How do I convert the decomposition of a homography matrix made in a right-hand coordinate system (i.e. x points right, y points down, z points into the scene) into a left-hand coordinate system (y points up)?

Given a homography H and, a camera matrix K, and their decomposition to rotation (R), translation (T), and normals (N) calculated for a right-hand coordinate system, how do I convert the decomposition (R, T, N) so it would fit the left-hand coordinate system described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting .. What is the purpose of this conversion ?

Comment: OpenCV have a build-in function: cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(). As far as I know, they are using a right-hand coordinate system while I need the results in a left-hand system...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a matrix from right-handed to left-handed coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263072/changing-a-matrix-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system)

Comment: Not exactly- I'm looking for a transformation of the decomposition result and not for the transformation of the coordinate system itself